# Trying to use Struct to make a String array and comparing it to a String

Tags: c, string, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Name {
   char Name[10];
}Name;

A(Name a) {
   Name NameList[16] = {"", "Holly", "Zia", "Brandon","Jerry","Tom","Katie","Klein","Sophie","Brian","Mary","Ben","Annie","Percy","Zoe","Zack"};
   
   for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
       if (a = NameList[i]) {
           for (int k = i; k <= 15; k++) {
               printf(NameList + k);
           }
           break;
       }

       else {
           continue;
       }
   }
}
```

I'm getting problems with if (a = NameList[i]) this part.. compiler tells me that I need pointers, but I'm not sure where I have to put them.. help?

Comment: In C you compare strings using `strcmp`.

Comment: Don't try to turn C into a language it is not. Just use `char *` for strings. All this type hiding is only going to hurt.

Comment: Where is `main`? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also post the exact error you are getting, and what you do not understand about it.

Answer (score 0):

1. `a = NameList[i]` is an assignment, not comparison. In general you need to use `==` for comparison.
2. In C a string is an array of chars, zero terminated. In order to compare strings in C you need to use [**`strcmp`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp). Note that it returns 0 if the strings are equal.
3. `a` is not actually a string, but contains one. `a.Name` is a string. Same applies to `NameList[i]`.
4. A struct should not contain a member with the same name as the struct itself (even if your compiler accepts it, it is error-prone). You should rename the member `Name` (e.g. to `data`).

Therefore after modifying the struct definition, you should change your `if` to:

```
if (strcmp(a.data, NameList[i].data) == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the statement if (a = NameList[i]) {bla..} does not do what you think it does. It first executes the command a = NameList[i] and then evaluates if (a != 0) in which case the commands inside the if statement will be executed.

That's a mistake everyone has made at some point ,even more experienced programmers might make this mistake from time to time.

Now I see you are trying to compare two strings ,in C we do this using the function strcmp(a ,b) .If strcmp returns 0 ,the two strings you gave it are equal.

Another mistake you made ,is that you are comparing two structs instead of their contents. You have to use if(!strcmp(a.Name ,NameList[i].Name)) instead.

So your main issue is that you are comparing structs not their contents.